# Android/add WebView doesn't work when adding it to a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I want to ad an Webview into a fragment. While it works fine when adding the to root (`frameRoot`), it doesn't work when adding it to the `LinearLayout layoutC`

The XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    tools:context="com.example.android.guernsyrestaurants.MenueFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/layoutC"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="menue" />


   </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

And the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menue,container,false);
        FrameLayout frameRoot = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.root);
        LinearLayout layoutC = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layoutC);

        WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());

        webView.loadUrl("http://url/");
        webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            root.getWidth(),
            root.getHeight()));

       // layoutC.addView(webView);
        frameRoot.addView(webView);

        return root;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: May be your are adding params with LinearLayout try adding generic layoutParams rather than adding specific to LinearLayout. or try to change them to FrameLayout.LayoutParams. It may help.

Comment: Your `TextView` is taking up all the space in the `LinearLayout`. There is no room for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set height of your TextView to `match_parent` and so it fills all the space on the screen. The WebView is added to layout but since TextView fills all the screen, you cannot see your WebView. Try setting `wrap_content` for the height of your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
 webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            root.getWidth(),
            root.getHeight()));
```

**to**

```
webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I occurred to this problem either, confused me for seconds, and i guess maybe it caused by not add the new LinearLayout into the origin xml,so i try to find some method like setContentView(R.layout.activity_four_model_test), and fortunately i found it. You need to add the COntentView after create it. Good Luck,Guy. But it will located at the top of the page, so you need to give more lacation attribution to it. :)

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(webView);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        **addContentView(linearLayout,params);**
```